# Find a rotation where the shape has the least width possible on the x-axis

Tags: algorithm, math

I am toying around with a shape problem and I am looking for a more clever solution than what I have been able to come up with.

Here is the problem:

I have a set of points that form an enclosed shape on a Cartesian grid, say A(-1,0),B(1,0), and C(0,4) which forms an acute triangle.

I have reworded this in a slightly less confusing way. Take the shape above and imagine that you can freely rotate it. I am looking to discover the rotation where we only take into account the x-axis and the distance between the western most and eastern most point is at its smallest.

When taking into account the shape above that distance would be the distance between A and B. While for more interesting shapes there may be shorter distances between points, I believe there is no way to rotate the shape above such that the western and eastern most points is less that the distance between A and B.

My only solution thus far has been to plot the points, rotate 1 degree, store the maximum distance keyed by the rotation. Rinse repeat and take the smallest one. This seems a bit kludgy and I know there has to be a more mathematically sound way to approach this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the principal component analysis and align the principle component to the y axis. This will optimize the "mean" square distance from every point to the y axis (i.e. width on x axis). Perhaps this is also optimal or close to the optimal by your criteria.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

**Alternative Solution (Optimal solution):**

First calculate the convex hull of the points. Note that the two points with maximum x width are always going to in the convex hull.

Now, for every line segment in the convex hull find the vertex that is farthest and note down the distance. Find the (line segment, farthest vertex) pair with minimum distance. Optimal rotation is the one that aligns that line segment in vertical direction.

Complexity: `O(nlogn)` for the convex hull part and `O(m^2)` for the second part where m is the number of points on the convex hull.

Comment: Minimizing the mean distance is not the same as minimizing the max-distance.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yes! That is why I said "Perhaps this is also optimal or close to the optimal by your criteria"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft See the optimal solution I just added.

Comment: The original answer is neither optimal nor "near optimal."  Imagine a lot of points clustered close together, and several points farther away; minimizing the mean will put the cluster near the y-axis, while the solution to OP's problem may have the cluster more towards the middle.  Now, perhaps PCA can also be used to find the solution to OP's problem *(I don't know enough about it)*, but if that's true it should be explained in your answer - as it stands, this is just an answer to a completely different problem.

Comment: and your new "optimal solution" is simply incorrect.  Imagine ex. a highly skewed parallelogram: in the optimal rotation *(where the perpendiculars of the closest two points are parallel to the x-axis)*, none of the points will have the same x- or y-values.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Is there any additional information I can provide to help you? I think I worded it a bit confusingly, but I can imagine shapes like a hour glass where finding the minimum distance when its upright yields the incorrect answer(the width of the narrowest part of the hourglass) when what I need is the answer to be the widest part of the hour glass(assuming the shape is taller than it is wide)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I don't understand your argument with the skewed parallelogram.  ElKamina is correct that the optimal solution will align on segment in the convex hull with the y axis.  The smallest distance in a triangle will always be an *altitude* of the triangle, hence we need to align the corresponding edge with the y axis.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Also, PCA *of the convex hull* will give a pretty good approximation.  The OP should comment on why he needs this and what's ther priority (ease of implementation, performance, accuracy, etc)

Comment: @nsfyn55 Note that an hourglass is not convex and the proposed solution started with the convex hull, therefore it'll not find the narrowest part.

Comment: This is not for anything hyper precise or complicated. This thing will in a majority of case have an array of ten or less cartesian points with each point connecting to the point of the next index to form a line and the last point pointing to the first to create a shape. I just need to find a way to rotate this thing so it has the smallest width possible with preference to simplicity over accuracy and performance

Comment: @nsfyn55 Well, the question is also how you are going to implement this.  If you use some technical computing system, then the advantage of PCA is that it's simple to implement.  In Mathematica, you can get the rotation matrix simply by `Last@SingularValueDecomposition@Part[points, ConvexHull[points]]`.  If you have to code all of it, then it's probably simpler to first find the convex hull, then find its smallest altitude ...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft My solution will still work for the skewed parallelogram

Comment: @Szabolcs: Ah, I see - I mistakenly thought *"that line segment"* in the second-to-last paragraph referred to the line-segment spanning the antipodal-pair *(line-segment, vertex)*.  I *believe* you're both right that this will work.  Note that the longest antipodal-pair can actually be found in `O(m log m)` by doing a binary-search on the dual graph.

Answer (score 1):

Let {N} be the set of points defining the smallest convex polygon that contains your shape, sorted in order clockwise.  For every edge (N - 1, N): determine the distance from this edge to the farthest-away point.  Take the shortest of these distances and rotate your shape such that the corresponding edge is perpendicular to the X axis.

Comment: This is the same what ElKamina said.  Perhaps a bit more clearly formulated.

Answer (score 1):

[Rotating Calipers](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/rotcal.html) is the good instrument to solve this problem.

More specifically, it is necessary to construct convex hull, then to find the width of a convex polygon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly certain of your grasp of mathematics, so please accept my apologies if this goes over your head, or if it is indeed too simply explained, but the solution that instantly stood out to me is to use Fourier analysis on a discrete sampling of the width of the polygon at fixed angles.

Your approach to rotate by a small amount and test could be considered a discrete sampling of a continuous function.

We know that there is a continuous function that defines the measure you are after for each possible rotation, you are just evaluating it at set points. i.e. an angle to polygon width function is known to exist, and we can evaluate the width of the polygon for a finite set of angles given enough time.

So, supposing we could find an expression in terms of elementary functions for this angle-to-width function, we could potentially determine exactly all of the angles which yield the minimum possible width by solving an equation.

We know that because you are rotating through 2PI radians, the width function will be 2PI periodic, and so you could perfectly reconstruct the function, given that enough angles were sampled, by applying Fourier analysis.

The question is, how many samples do you need to produce a perfect reconstruction of the function?

I think it's determined by the smallest distance between the boundary points.

```
ceil(perimiterLength/smallestDistanceBetweenPoints);
```

In short, I am resampling the perimiter of the boundary by placing evenly spaced samples along the perimiter, using a spacing that is equal to or smaller than the smallest distance. Let's call this number n. (To be honest I am not overly certain if this is correct)

Sample easterly and westerly points at n points at evenly spaced angles through 2PI radians, and plot their difference as an n-point angle to width function.

Take the Fourier transform of this graph to give you the sets of real Fourier series coefficients needed to define the distance function

Use any of your favourite methods for identifying the the minimum value of a function.

So I suppose for you triangle example you determine that you need ceil(3 + root(3)) = 5 samples. Calculate the distance at 0 2pi/5 4pi/5 6pi/6 and 8pi/5, take the Fourier transform of this result and reconstruct the signal, creating a formula like

```
a0 + a1 sin (t) + a2 sin (2t)
```

And then you have to determine the minimum of this function (for which there are many options)